# How to remove duplicate xml nodes with attribute using LINQ?

Tags: xml

I have following xml structure:

```
    <movie>
    <profile>
    </profile>
    <address>
    </address>
    <Details detail1="1" detail2="1">
        <moviestart>09:20:00</moviestart>
        <movietime date="2015-01-20" hour="07:05:00" />
        <code>BA</code>
        <moviearrive code="MAH" place="MAHARASHTRA" />
        <moviedepart code="JAM" place="JAMMU" />
        <TYPE>STD</TYPE>
    </Details>
    <Details detail1="2" detail2="2">
        <moviestart>08:00:00</moviestart>
        <movietime date="2015-01-25" hour="07:35:00" />
        <code>BI</code>
        <moviearrive code="BIH" place="Bihar" />
        <moviedepart code="MYS" place="Mysore" />
        <TYPE>STD</TYPE>
    </Details>
    <Details detail1="1" detail2="1">
        <moviestart>09:20:00</moviestart>
        <movietime date="2015-01-20" hour="07:05:00" />
        <code>BA</code>
        <moviearrive code="MAH" place="MAHARASHTRA" />
        <moviedepart code="JAM" place="JAMMU" />
        <TYPE>STD</TYPE>
    </Details>
    <Details detail1="2" detail2="2">
        <moviestart>08:00:00</moviestart>
        <movietime date="2015-01-25" hour="07:35:00" />
        <code>BI</code>
        <moviearrive code="BIH" place="Bihar" />
        <moviedepart code="MYS" place="Mysore" />
        <TYPE>STD</TYPE>
    </Details>
</movie>
```

Wanted to eliminate last two sets of details section after comparing each and every value of element and attributes. I tried with below code however no luck.

```
var elements = (from el in doc.Descendants("movie").Descendants("Details")
                            select el).GroupBy(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.First());
```

Above code works good for element value and ignores attribute value.
How can I remove those duplicates after comparing?

After the duplicate removal xml should look like below:

```
<movie>
    <profile>
    </profile>
    <address>
    </address>
    <Details detail1="1" detail2="1">
        <moviestart>09:20:00</moviestart>
        <movietime date="2015-01-20" hour="07:05:00" />
        <code>BA</code>
        <moviearrive code="MAH" place="MAHARASHTRA" />
        <moviedepart code="JAM" place="JAMMU" />
        <TYPE>STD</TYPE>
    </Details>
    <Details detail1="2" detail2="2">
        <moviestart>08:00:00</moviestart>
        <movietime date="2015-01-25" hour="07:35:00" />
        <code>BI</code>
        <moviearrive code="BIH" place="Bihar" />
        <moviedepart code="MYS" place="Mysore" />
        <TYPE>STD</TYPE>
    </Details>
</movie>
```

One more clarification,
if the xml is slightly modified as below :

```
<movie>
    <profile>
    </profile>
    <address>
    </address>
    <Details detail1="1" detail2="1">
        <moviestart>09:20:00</moviestart>
        <movietime date="2015-01-20" hour="07:05:00" />
        <code>BA</code>
        <moviearrive code="MAH" place="MAHARASHTRA" />
        <moviedepart code="JAM" place="JAMMU" />
        <TYPE>STD</TYPE>
    </Details>
    <Details detail1="2" detail2="1">
        <moviestart>08:00:00</moviestart>
        <movietime date="2015-01-25" hour="07:35:00" />
        <code>BI</code>
        <moviearrive code="BIH" place="Bihar" />
        <moviedepart code="MYS" place="Mysore" />
        <TYPE>STD</TYPE>
    </Details>
    <Details detail1="1" detail2="2">
        <moviestart>09:20:00</moviestart>
        <movietime date="2015-01-20" hour="07:05:00" />
        <code>BA</code>
        <moviearrive code="MAH" place="MAHARASHTRA" />
        <moviedepart code="JAM" place="JAMMU" />
        <TYPE>STD</TYPE>
    </Details>
    <Details detail1="2" detail2="2">
        <moviestart>08:00:00</moviestart>
        <movietime date="2015-01-25" hour="07:35:00" />
        <code>BI</code>
        <moviearrive code="BIH" place="Bihar" />
        <moviedepart code="MYS" place="Mysore" />
        <TYPE>STD</TYPE>
    </Details>
</movie>
```

Only the attributes of Details having different values.. Any suggestions pls?

Comment: attribute value of which element?

Comment: It should check all the elements as well as attributes... Not checking the particular element/attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`XNode.DeepEquals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if two nodes have same markup, for example :

```
var details = doc.Descendants("Details").ToList();
foreach (XElement detail in details)
{
    //get node other than current detail having same markup as detail
    var duplicate = doc.Descendants("Details")
                       .FirstOrDefault(o => o != detail && XNode.DeepEquals(o, detail));
    //if exist, current detail is duplicate -> remove it
    if(duplicate != null) detail.Remove();
}
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

**Output :**

```
<movie>
  <profile></profile>
  <address></address>
  <Details detail1="1" detail2="1">
    <moviestart>09:20:00</moviestart>
    <movietime date="2015-01-20" hour="07:05:00" />
    <code>BA</code>
    <moviearrive code="MAH" place="MAHARASHTRA" />
    <moviedepart code="JAM" place="JAMMU" />
    <TYPE>STD</TYPE>
  </Details>
  <Details detail1="2" detail2="2">
    <moviestart>08:00:00</moviestart>
    <movietime date="2015-01-25" hour="07:35:00" />
    <code>BI</code>
    <moviearrive code="BIH" place="Bihar" />
    <moviedepart code="MYS" place="Mysore" />
    <TYPE>STD</TYPE>
  </Details>
</movie>
```

Another approach based on LINQ query you have tried, this print the same result :

```
var elements = (from el in doc.Descendants("movie").Descendants("Details")
                select el).GroupBy(x => x.ToString())
                          .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                          .Select(x => x.First());
foreach (XElement element in elements)
{
    element.Remove();
}
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```